# How to prepopulate the form data into a document within a docusign envelope using API?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a business case where we are trying to resend the envelope to the user to make any edits. We need to GET the form data from an existing envelope that the user completed, create a new envelope with the same document using a POST and pass in the form data (either at time of creation of the envelope or a separate POST/PUT call to update the document) so when we send this envelope to the user, it already has the prepopulated data and they just need to edit the fields they want to and sign it again rather than having to refill the whole form.

I have successfully copied an existing envelope and create a new envelope with the same document. But it does not copy the form data so that's where I am stuck.

Comment: Please provide what you've done so far.

Comment: I have copied an existing envelope that is already completed and its document has form data.
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes Payload =  
{ 
 "status": "sent",
    "envelopeId": "envelopeId of the envelope we want to copy",
    "emailSubject": "API Signature Request",
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "email": "monasmith@test.com",
            "name": "Mona Smith",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "routingOrder": "1"
        }]
    }
}
This created a new envelope with the same document but no form data.